# How do I abort fc without executing the command?

Tags: bash, command-history

The command fc will allow visual editing of the previous command. If I change my mind in the editor, how do I stop the command from being executed. In vim, typing q! or q both result in the command being executed and CTRL-C doesn't work either. Is the only option to delete the command in the editor and then wq?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From vi you can type `:cq` to exit without saving and with a non-zero return code. In this case the command will not be repeated.

Alternatively, you can usually suspend the editor with <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> which gets you back to the shell without redoing the command. You still have to `fg` to restart the editor, but the tmp file will no longer be around, so you can safely quit the editor. Or you can `kill -9 %` this suspended editor.

I agree, it could be easier. Of course, you can always edit lines within bash using vi or emacs commands.

Comment: vi does not have a command ":cq". Did you like to type ":q!"?

Comment: @schily sorry, by vi I was assuming vim. You can read about vim `cq` in [quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, vim is not POSIX compliant (besides enhancements there are deviations). For a generic help, it is usually a good idea not to depend on local or vendor unique enhancements. BTW: :q! is sufficient as a POSIX vi will exit != 0 in this case.

Comment: @schily Depending on vim being installed is probably safe in most cases, and in this case the asker specifically said `q!` didn't work for them

Comment: :cq worked for me. I should have said vim, not vi. I updated the question accordingly and considered your answer sufficient. Thanks also to @schily for the additional note, however q! in vim still executes the command if it is left in the buffer.

Comment: This is because there was no error and thus the exit code is 0. In vi it works to type :c (results in an illegal command message) and then to type :q! and the remembered error results in an exit code != 0. This however does not work in vim. My previous assumption that :q! always results in an exit code != 0 was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, an easier way to remember is to delete the command (dd should do) and quit (`ZZ` or any other way to quit with saving should do).  IMHO, `:cq` is quite arcane.