# How to cancel edit-and-execute-command?

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there a way to not execute a command, once I have pressed *Ctrl+X Ctrl+E*? (`edit-and-execute-command`)

Ideally like in git: If I save the file (like :wq in vim), it gets executed, but if I close the file without saving, (like :q! in vim), the command doesn't get executed.

Comment: @doneal24 `^x^e` is bound to `edit-and-execute-command`. I think this is standard, but I've updated the question now.

Comment: @Quasímodo thank you! I didn't know about `cq`! If you add an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can't you just delete everything and save a blank file?

Comment: [ctrl-x-e without executing command immediately](https://superuser.com/q/1601543/432690). Then you ctrl+c.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I abort fc without executing the command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226421/how-do-i-abort-fc-without-executing-the-command)

Comment: Why not just comment out the command in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

To cancel execution of the command, completely erase the contents of the file before saving it and quitting the editor.

Interestingly, using this method, the original unedited command is still saved in the history.

Note: this answer was suggested in a comment -- I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the course of normal line editing, I've cultivated the habit of putting a `#`  prefix at the beginning of the line.  This allows me to look over a complex command to ensure that it's correct, or perhaps to save a "draft" of a command in my history while I go research some other point of information that I need to formulate and check the precise syntax of the draft command.

Presuming you're editing just a one-line command, from within `vi`, do:

`1Gi#`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Then save the file, and your "draft" command will not be executed, but will be stored in your `bash` history.  When you're ready, you can return to the command, remove the leading `#`  and execute the command.